# PHP Keep entered values after validation error

Tags: php, validation, error-handling

I have a simple form that needed validation. 
I did this with the `empty()` function. If the validation doesn't pass it gives the user an alert. As soon as this alert is created all entered values are gone.

I would like to keep them.

This is what I did:

```
<form id="" name="" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
    if($_POST["submit"]){
        if (!empty ($_POST["name"])){
          // do something
        }else{
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('U heeft niet alle velden ingevuld. Graag een volledig ingevuld formulier versturen');
            </script>
            <?php
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass that entered value as a default value to input:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: Yes this did it. I understand.. Thnx!

Comment: You should also sanitise the $_POST before outputting the value to prevent injection of bad code. i.e. <?php echo isset($_POST["name"]) ? htmlentities($_POST["name"]) : ''; ?>

Answer (score 6):

Bizarrely I happen to be working on a similar thing and have been using the following to ensre that form data is available after submission of the form. It uses a session variable to store the results of the POST and is used as the value in the form field.

```
/* Store form values in session var */
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ) $_SESSION[ 'formfields' ][ $field ]=$value;
}

/* Function used in html - provides previous value or empty string */
function fieldvalue( $field=false ){
        return ( $field && !empty( $field ) && isset( $_SESSION[ 'formfields' ] ) && array_key_exists( $field, $_SESSION[ 'formfields' ] ) ) ? $_SESSION[ 'formfields' ][ $field ] : '';
}

/* example */
echo "<input type='text' id='username' name='username' value='".fieldvalue('username')."' />";
```

Comment: This works magically. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to this for every input field:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>">
```

It checks if you already submitted the form once, if so put the value in the textbox.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the last option, but for some reason it didn't work on my end. Maybe I did it wrong, but I just added the line above in my html file of the contact form.