# Save image on input after POST validation fails

Tags: php

I have an form that I submit which has among other inputs, an image input like so:

```
<label id="labelEnviarImagem" for='enviarImagem'>Choose a file &#187;</label><br>
<input required type="file" name="productFile" id="enviarImagem">
```

My problem is the following:

Sometimes, other inputs from the form won't be valid, and the PHP will return the user to the form page while saving the previous values on the `$_SESSION` so the user has the form pre-filled and will be able to fix their mistakes without having to re-type everything. How can I do the same for the image?

I've tried to save the image on the session and then pass that as the value to the input, but obviously it didn't work.

```
$_SESSION["dadosProduct"]["img"] = $_FILES['productFile']['tmp_name'];

<input required type="file" name="productFile" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['dadosProduct']) ? $_SESSION['dadosProduct']['name'] : ""; ?>" id="enviarImagem">
```

My question is: I can save the information when the input type is text/number by using the `$_SESSION` easily, how can I do the same when the `input type="file"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Keep entered values after validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276966/php-keep-entered-values-after-validation-error)

Comment: Not a duplicate, my code is relative to the input of the type file. As you can see I've already tried to solve the problem using the path that's explained on that question.

Comment: @AntonioNeto You can do 1 think before checking the server side validation upload the file to server and store the value in session. and display those session image on form if validation fail. Its a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to save the image on the session

There are two problems with your attempt to do that.

## Garbage collection

You are storing the filename in the session, but as soon as the script finishes [the file will be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131226/php-when-does-the-temporary-uploaded-files-get-deleted), so you are storing the name of a file that no longer exists.

You need to store the file somewhere more permanent (and implement your own garbage collection to clean it up after some time has passed).

## File inputs

A file input is designed to upload files from the computer hosting the browser.

Setting the value of it to the path of a file on the server makes no sense (and you can't set the value of a file input anyway).

You need to provide some other kind of UI.

This might just be a plain paragraph that states a file, with the name `whatever.ext` has been stored in the user's session.

Comment: So, in theory. I should upload the file to the server to a temporary place, and have the information that a temporary file has been uploaded saved on the session, so when the user tries to send the form again i'll be able to use his previous file?