# Can't keep values inside the field after failing to pass validation

Tags: php, html

Basically i want to keep the values that weren't wrong and were not password or repeat password. For that i followed this question:

[PHP Keep entered values after validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276966/php-keep-entered-values-after-validation-error).

Though, only last name is kept the way I tried. The way i am trying to do that for all fields in my form is currently: `"<?php echo isset($_GET["email"]) ? $_GET["email"] : ''; ?>"`. I also have errors message that reads from the URL using $_GET and sends an error message accordingly, which works fine. This is my actual code.

```html
<form method="post" action="includes/signup.inc.php" id="create_customer" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="create_customer" /><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓" />
<div id="first_name" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="fname" class="login">Nome</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["fname"])){echo($_GET["fname"]);}?>" name="fname" id="fname" class="large" size="30" />
</div>
<div id="last_name" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="lname" class="login">Sobrenome</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["fname"])){echo($_GET["fname"]);}?>" name="lname" id="lname" class="large" size="30" /></div>
<div id="email" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="email" class="login">E-mail</label> <input type="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["email"]) ? $POST["email"] : ''; ?>" name="email" id="email" class="large" size="30" /></div>
<div id="password" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="password" class="login">Senha</label> <input type="password" value="" name="pwd" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
<div id="password" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="password" class="login">Repetir Senha</label> <input type="password" value="" name="pwd-repeat" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
</div>
<div class="acceptsMarketing"> <input type="checkbox" id="customer[accepts_marketing]" name="customer[accepts_marketing]"> <label for="customer[accepts_marketing]">Assine a nossa
newsletter?</label></div>
<div class="action_bottom"> <input class="btn action_button" name="signup-submit" type="submit" value="Inscrever-se" />
<p class="right" style="padding-top: 8px;">
<input class="btn action_button" type="submit" value="Recuperar Senha" />
<p class="right" style="padding-top: 8px;">
Já é cliente? <a href="login.php" id="customer_login_link">Entrar →</a></p>
</div>
</form>
</div><!-- /#create-customer -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Originally not known to me, here goes to validation codes for errors display:

```
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=emptyfields&fname=" . $fname . "&lname" . $lname . "&email" . $email);
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($fname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $fname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=nomeinvalido&fname=" . $fname);
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($lname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $lname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=sobrenomeinvalido&lname=" . $lname.  "&lname");
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $email)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidmail&email=" . $email);
        exit();
    } else if ($pwd !== $pwdrepeat) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=passwordcheck&fname=");
        exit();
```

Comment: This same form appeared yesterday in your previous question and I mentioned then that your HTML was incorrect - it remains unchanged... why?

Comment: Updated code formatting

Comment: @RamRaider i did clarify that the div was correct. Also updating some tests i tried doing "<?php if(isset($_GET["fname"])){echo($_GET["fname"]);}?>" and it saved the first name field, however if i do for $_GET["lname"] it doesn't save, if i repeat $_GET["fname" for all fields, it saves...

Comment: The above form is not correctly formed. There are an unbalanced number of elements and duplicate ids

Comment: True. Still, formatting it will do little to solve my issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain the value of the various form elements you could us e a very simple little function and simply supply the form element name as a parameter, like so:

```
<?php
    function getvalue( $name=false ){
        echo isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) ? $_POST[ $name ] : '';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Form value retention</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--
            for demonstration, the action has been 
             removed so it POSTs to the same page.
        -->
        <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $_POST, true ) );
            }

        ?>

        <form method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

            <input type='hidden' name='form_type' value='create_customer' />
            <input type='hidden' name='utf8' value='✓' />

            <div id='first_name' class='clearfix large_form'> 
                <label for='fname' class='login'>Nome</label>
                <input type='text' value='<?php getvalue('fname'); ?>' name='fname' class='large' size='30' />
            </div>

            <div id='last_name' class='clearfix large_form'> 
                <label for='lname' class='login'>Sobrenome</label>
                <input type='text' value='<?php getvalue('lname'); ?>' name='lname' class='large' size='30' />
            </div>

            <div id='email' class='clearfix large_form'> 
                <label for='email' class='login'>E-mail</label>
                <input type='email' value='<?php getvalue('email'); ?>' name='email' class='large' size='30' />
            </div>

            <div class='clearfix large_form'>

                <label for='password' class='login'>Senha</label>
                <input type='password' value='<?php getvalue('pwd');?>' name='pwd' class='large password' size='30' />

                <div id='password' class='clearfix large_form'>
                    <label for='password' class='login'>Repetir Senha</label>
                    <input type='password' value='<?php getvalue('pwd-repeat');?>' name='pwd-repeat' class='large password' size='30' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='acceptsMarketing'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='customer[accepts_marketing]'>
                <label for='customer[accepts_marketing]'>Assine a nossa newsletter?</label>
            </div>

            <div class='action_bottom'>

                <input class='btn action_button' name='signup-submit' type='submit' value='Inscrever-se' />

                <p class='right' style='padding-top: 8px;'>
                    <input class='btn action_button' type='submit' value='Recuperar Senha' />
                </p>

                <p class='right' style='padding-top: 8px;'>
                    Já é cliente? <a href='login.php' id='customer_login_link'>Entrar →</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML in the form has been corrected in, what I believe is, the most logical way though I removed the ID attributes as many were duplicated. That said the form values are maintained upon form submission - because it is the same page. To accomplish this after submitting to a-n-other script you would use a session variable to keep track of the POST array.

When using another script for the form action ( to perform validation etc ) the form values would not be retained when that other script redirects back if it finds an error. To solve that a session variable would work well.

So, in the above - at the beginning of the form action page:

```
session_start();
$svar='formdata';
/* the session variable is populated when the form is submitted */
if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    $_SESSION[ $svar ]=$_POST;
}
/* other processing... if(error)->redirect etc */
```

And the alternative function to `getvalue` in the above page:

```
session_start();
$svar='formdata';

function getsessionvalue( $name=false ){
    global $svar;
    echo isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ][ $name ] ) ? $_SESSION[ $svar ][ $name ] : '';
}
```

Comment: Nice, very simple, easy to understand and works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped. This is fine when posting to the same page but if the form posted to another script that did validation and then redirected if there were errors it would not work - which is where a session variable would come in. I'll add an alternative function to illustrate.

Comment: Yes, it worked well, just took a minute or so to see what i was doing wrong, after i passed the function to get the values it worked really good

Answer (score 0):

You send data via POST method (form method="post") but try to set it from $_GET array. Use $_POST instead. Also do not forget escape inputted data to avoid XSS vulnerability

Comment: I was using $_POST initially, no fields were saved at all.

Comment: Ok, looks like you redirects from includes/signup.inc.php back to form with errors and received data. If so - could you provide URL?

Comment: which url you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $_REQUEST, this gets the results from all $_GET and $_POST data.
See http://www.shodor.org/~kevink/phpTutorial/nileshc_getreqpost.php for more info

Comment: it was keeping just 1 field though