# PHP : Redisplay form with inputted values if submits fail

Tags: php

My username is a primary key. When the user submits form and found out that theres a duplicate username, the sql will fails. I want to redisplay the form with inputted values from the user if the submission fails. How can i do that ?

I tried to user if(isset) method and windows.location.href back to the same page, it clears the inserted values.

I also tried to just echo the alert script without the window.location.href, it clears everything out.

How can i redisplay the form with inserted values in textboxes if the submission fails ?

Here is my code.

```
include('sql_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // code...

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`Username`, `Password`) VALUES ('$username' , '$password') ";
  if (!mysqli_query($connection , $sql)){

      echo"<script>alert('Failed');</script>";

  }
  else {
    echo"<script>alert('$type INSERTED');window.location.href='test3.php';</script>";
  }
}
else {
  // code...


 ?>

<form class="" action="test.php" method="post">

Username : <input type="text" name="username" value=""> <br>
Password : <input type="text" name="password" value="">

<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

} ?>
```

Comment: you can use validation on the frontend to avoid the long process.

Comment: Don’t redirect elsewhere, just output the form _again_ - this time pre-filling the `value` attribute of your text input fields with the values you just received.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Keep entered values after validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276966/php-keep-entered-values-after-validation-error)

Comment: @04FS yep! thank you. I really dont know the exact thing to what to google for it thats why i asked. THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

You can use session for that set others fields in session and in html fields

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
 }
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){echo 
$_SESSION['email'];}?>">
```

Comment: _“You can use session for that”_ - or you can just use `$_POST['email']` for that, which you already have at this point in this situation …